# How to pass id from Index View to create method of another Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc in asp.net. What i want to do is: I have a view(Index) of Item Controller and a create method of Order controller. Index view code is:

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcHotel.Models.Items>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
//var item = Model;
}
//other markup
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<div class="col-md-2">
    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="/Item/RetrieveImage/@item.Id" />
      <div>
        <p>@item.ItemName</p>
        <p>Rs.<span>@item.Price</span>

        <a href="?/order/create/@item.Id"><span class="pull-right">Order Now &nbsp;</span></a>
        <p class="text-warning"><span>@item.Rating stars</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    db = new DBContext();
    //var categories = new SelectList(new[] { "Rice","Karachi","Fast Food","Drinks", "Shakes" });
    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
    return View();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MvcHotel.Models.Order order)
{
    //HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
    //int i = UploadImageInDataBase(file, order);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db = new DBContext();
        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return Index();

 }
```

Now i want to pass item id so that item name and its category automatically display in dropdown list of Create(View) of order. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model class to serve your view:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Create an instance of that and populate it in your controller and then paas it to the `View` method within your `Create(int id)` action:

```
return View(instanceHere);
```

Then use it in your view:

```
@model ItemModel
```